# What is num_outputs equivalent for tensorflow.contrib.layers.convolution2d for Theano?

Tags: tensorflow, theano

In Tensorflow-contrib, the [2D convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) is defined in terms of filter_size and num_outputs. How do you control num_outputs in Theano's [nnet.conv2d](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d) type?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it has to be determined at runtime, from the shape of filters tensor.

---

Unlike TF, Theano don't store explicit shape information in tensors.

In TF, you can do:

```
w = tf.placeholder('float32', [64,64], name='w')
```

In Theano, there's no way to tell `x` is a `64 x 64` matrix at compile time. The best you can do is:

```
w = T.matrix(name='w', dtype='float32')
```

At compile time, Theano only knows about the tensor rank, and which dimensions are broadcastable.

At runtime, the shape of tensors are known. If images batch is a 4D tensor of shape `[N, C, H, W]`, and filters are of size `[D, C, U, V]`. The `num_outputs` will inferred as `D`.

---

**EDIT** actually you can specify `filter_shape` argument in `theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d`, however it just provides a hint for Theano to choose optimal algorithm for convolution. The shape mismatch error still has to be determined at runtime.